# retrieve street address from a given latitude and longitude

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, reverse-geocoding, cllocation

I have the following code which takes my lat and lng, reverse-geocodes it, and gives me a street address:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if ([locations lastObject]) {
        [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:[locations lastObject] completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            NSLog(@"%@", placemark.thoroughfare);
        }
    }];
}
```

The output from the last if-statement is `(null)`.

If I use `placemark.postalCode` instead, it works. I checked out Apples documentation on [CLPlacemarks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html), and don't see any reason as to why my code would give me the error it does.

Comment: The output is (null). - What output is null?

Comment: You have two NSLog statements, which one outputs (null)?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha the nslog in the last if-statement

Comment: but you said If I use placemark.postalCode instead, it works. You've got placemark.postalCode there

Comment: @javadog36 I updated the code a little bit - and the last if statement

Comment: @AndreyChernukha i updated the code 'placemark.thoroughfare' gives me null

Comment: Is it just the thoroughfare that isn't available? Did you check all other properties?

Comment: @Wain the properties that DOES NOT work: subAdministrativeArea, thoroughfare, subThoroughfare

Comment: Have you tried with different locations? Is it just that Apple doesn't have much information for the location you're testing?

Comment: @JamesFrost Actually I tried the same code on an actual iPhone, and it worked, so the problem has something to do with the simulator, which is nice to know